# ArcGIS JS - Are spatial sub-queries possible?

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I begin by querying a feature layer of polygons using a graphic. That runs succesfully and then my callback function aims to take the results of that first query (returned as polygons and then merged into a single polygon using Union) and query it again. However, queryFeatures and queryTask only work with URLs/feature layers. Is there a way to perform a query/sub-query on a polygon?

Below I have a truncated version of my code. I go through the first query in queryShapes and subsequently create a polygon out of the results, which is **housUnionPoly** that you see at the end of the second function. **housUnionPoly** is the polygon that I am trying to query again. Of course, the error I get is at that last line that says that queryFeatures is not a function of polygons.

```
        queryShapes = function () {
            var q = new Query();
            q.geometry = unionGFX.geometry;
            q.spatialRelationship = Query.SPATIAL_REL_INTERSECTS;
            q.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
            q.outFields = ["*"];
            q.returnGeometry = true;
            //query floodzones
            var qTask = new QueryTask("URL");
            qTask.execute(q);
            qTask.on("complete", subQuery);

        };

        function subQuery() {
                    var queryHouse = new Query();
                    queryHouse.geometry = floodUnionGFX.geometry;
                    queryHouse.spatialRelationship = Query.SPATIAL_REL_INTERSECTS;
                    queryHouse.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
                    queryHouse.outFields = ["*"];
                    queryHouse.returnGeometry = true;

                    houseUnionPoly.queryFeatures(queryHouse, selectpolyHousing);
                };
```

If it helps, the sub selection is essentialy the intersection of two graphics. Alternatively, if I could perform a query on the original layer using the intersection of two graphics on that layer, that would be great.